# Set properties of modelitem

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, qt5, stylesheet, pyqt5

I have a model/view three with elements which I would like to color differently. I can achieve this by:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QVariant, QModelIndex, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 4

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return f'{index.row()} - {index.column()}'
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.column() % 2:
                return QColor(Qt.green)
            else:
                return QColor(Qt.blue)
        elif role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if index.row() % 2:
                return QColor(Qt.black)
            else:
                return QColor(Qt.red)
        else:
            return QVariant()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
model = Model()
view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

resulting in the desired result:

[image]

However in this case the model needs to know the color information and changing it afterwards is not possible without touching the code. Is there a way to define something like a `listViewItemProperty` which I could use with a `stylesheet`?

For `QListWidget` I can set properties which I can set properties and afterwards I can use them within stylesheets like:

```
QListWidgetItem[valid="true"] {
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Ideally I would like to return a few boolean flags in the model. And then in the stylesheet define how it will be drawn. If possible I want to avoid `delegates`.

Comment: Presumably, a `QTableWidget` is stylable in the same way a `QListWidget` is.

Comment: @ekhumoro. This I know, but how would I style a `QTableViewItem` with a custom property and how would I set one?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming in exactly the same way you showed in your question. It somewhat suprises me that properties would work with `QListWidgetItem`, though, given that it is not a subclass of `QObject`. I haven't got around to testing this for myself, yet.

Comment: @ekhumoro. I must be missing something obvious. How would I make this work with `Model/View`?

Comment: A `QListWidget` and a `QTableWidget` are both model/views. You didn't make it completely clear that this *must* work with a custom model. If that is the case, there is no way to use stylesheets to style individual items. There is, of course, the `QTableView::item` selector, but that mostly applies styles to all items. But I really don't understand why you can't just add some methods to the custom model for setting the colours. There's nothing forcing you to hard code them.